Sequence was not added, no data available (SEQ MAN)
I am processing my sequences using the software seqman, but when I try to upload my ab1 OR phd documents, the electropherogram doesnt appear or a message tells me "Sequence xxx was not added, no data available",enter image description here
I tried oppening the ab1 file and the phd file, but with no sucess in both. I expect any help that I could understand better what is happening

I just discovered that in Geneious you can see the forward and reverse sequence with the graphics and can create the consensus while checking the quality in the eletropherogram
